# Cygwin: interrupting blocking read

Tags: linux, unix, io, cygwin, signals

I've written the program which spawns a thread that reads in a loop from stdin in a blocking fashion. I want to make the thread return from blocked read immediately. I've registered my signal handler (with sigaction and without SA_RESTART flag) in the reading thread, send it a signal and expect read to exit with EINTR error. But it doesn't happen. Is it issue or limitation of Cygwin or am I doing something wrong? 
Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <pthread.h>

pthread_t thread;
volatile int run = 0;
void root_handler(int signum)
{
    printf("%s ENTER (thread is %x)\n", __func__, pthread_self());
    run = 0;
}


void* thr_func(void*arg)
{  int res;
   char buffer[256];
   printf("%s ENTER (thread is %x)\n", __func__, pthread_self());
   struct sigaction act;
    memset (&act, 0, sizeof(act));
    act.sa_sigaction = &root_handler;
    //act.sa_flags = SA_RESTART;

    if (sigaction(SIGUSR1, &act, NULL) < 0) {
        perror ("sigaction error");
        return 1;
    }
   while(run)
   {
       res = read(0,buffer, sizeof(buffer));
       if(res == -1)
       {
          if(errno == EINTR)
          {
             puts("read was interrupted by signal");  
          }
       }
       else
       {
           printf("got: %s", buffer);
       }
   }
   printf("%s LEAVE (thread is %x)\n", __func__, pthread_self());
}

int main() {
    run = 1;
    printf("root thread: %x\n", pthread_self());

    pthread_create(&thread, NULL, &thr_func, NULL);
    printf("thread %x started\n", thread);
    sleep(4);
    pthread_kill(thread, SIGUSR1 );
    //raise(SIGUSR1);
    pthread_join(thread, NULL);
    return 0;
}
```

I'm using Cygwin (1.7.32(0.274/5/3)).

Answer (score 0):

I've just tried to do the same on Ubuntu and it works (I needed to include signal.h, though, even though in Cygwin it compiled as it is). It seems to be peculiarity of Cygwin's implementation.